# Authenticating Iphone Login with PHP/MySQL and HTTP Responses

Tags: objective-c, authentication

Im trying to create a iPhone Objective C login page using PHP/MySQL to authenticate. Im trying to use HTTP responses as a way of authenticating. Right now it always fails to login , regardless of what you enter.

```
`- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{
// this part isnt really implemented yet!
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];




NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MY URL HERE.php"];


 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

 NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)request;
 responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];


 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:response error:nil];




 if ([responseStatusCode statusCode] == 200) {
   //do something
   UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"Your have logged in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
   [alertsuccess show];
   [alertsuccess release];
  }

  else   {
   NSLog(@"Login failed.");
   //do something else
   UIAlertView *alertfail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"fail" message:@"login fail" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
   [alertfail show];
   [alertfail release];
  }
`
```

and the PHP looks like

```
    <?
session_start();
require("iphoneconnection.php");

$u = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

$check = "SELECT username, password FROM iphoneusers WHERE username='$u' AND password= '$pw'";



$login = mysql_query($check, $connect) or die(mysql_error());


// check user level and store in $row

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
//$_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $u;
echo 'login success';
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

//header("Location: index.php");

} else {
//header("Location: login.php");
//echo '403 Forbidden';
header("403 Forbidden");
}

mysql_close($connect);


?>
```

Anyone got any pointers? Even if its just to tell me if Im formatting my repsonses correctly in the PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I got it to work using:

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"MY URL.php?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];

} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fail" message:@"Invalid Access"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];

}

loginIndicator.hidden = FALSE;
[loginIndicator startAnimating];
loginButton.enabled = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the sample you've given, I don't see that you're actually sending the username & password with the request. You're creating a string "post", but never including it in the request.

Also, this cast:

`NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)request;`

doesn't look right. Why are you typecasting the request object to a response?