# Connecting To MySQL Database with my iOS App

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I am writing an iOS app for my school to keep track of pupil's rewards, grades, etc.
I need to connect to a MySQL online database with my app, I need to be able to upload to it, query it, and download the results to display in my app.

I think I need to do this via a PHP page, however there is no reasonably clear tutorial on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webserver with a PHP/ASP/JSP/etc script to interact with the database. Create an API with common operations like SELECT, UPDATE or INSERT, and then call this url's inside the iOS app.

Usefull links:

- [Making HTTP and HTTPS Requests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)
- [Sending HTTP-Post ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-http-post-ios)
- [Authenticating Iphone Login with PHP/MySQL and HTTP Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407973/authenticating-iphone-login-with-php-mysql-and-http-responses)

Comment: Thanks! Those links are great! Any ideas on how to download the results of a query?

Comment: mmmm you can print the resultset as JSON. Ovjective-C can parse JSON: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c