# Connect to MySql database through xamarin

Tags: mysql, ios, xamarin

I'm currently doing a iOS application for school to connect to school mysql database.
It should be able to connect to it through the tools on xamarin studio.
I tried a lot of different coding to connect the database, but was unable to do so.
Is there any tutorial or example code to let me learn on how to do it ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your solution will be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830575/connecting-to-mysql-database-with-my-ios-app

Comment: You can try this suggestion on xamarin forum - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4048/mysql-access-for-android-and-iphone-apps

Answer (score 5):

Do not connect directly to a database from a mobile app.  Doing this requires exposing your database server directly to the web, which is a horrible security risk.  The better approach is to use a web services layer to broker the interaction between your client and your server.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: how do I use web services through xamarin ?
I thought of trying it out whether it works first before moving on to web services. Is it possible to connect directly ?

Comment: You use them the same way you consume web services in any .NET app.  I posted a link to the Xamarin docs on web services.

Comment: okay. May I know which works best in my situation? REST, WCF or SOAP ?

Comment: REST is usually simplest.

Comment: Alright, now what if we actually want to connect directly to a database, for example to make a database management app? This doesn't answer the question, it advises against it.

Answer (score 0):

While people are right and the best way to connect to a database is to use a web service there are some times you want to connect directly and ways to make the connection more secure (ip restrictions on the mysql server).

Here is a plugin with code examples on how to do it:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

Be sure to pay attention to the first forum question on errors and how to resolve.  You need to include a reference to system.data, I18N, I18N.West in your project and also make a call to the constructor for I18N somewhere in your code.

new I18N.West.CP1250();