# Could not load assemblies System.Configuration.Install - Xamarin / MySQL

Tags: c#, android, mysql, mono, xamarin

I am currently trying to build my first app on android. 
It has to have a database, I use MySQL. Xamarin and C# for the code.

I am trying to connect my app to the database, and i still pick this error :

```
Exception while loading assemblies : System.IO.FileNotFoundException:Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKey Token = b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for android profile?

What does that mean? I followed step by step the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL).

Can you help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

System.Configuration.* is not an .NET assembly that is part of Mono for Android and thus isn't available in Xamarin.Android.

A list of available assemblies can be found at: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/

As a solution I suggest reading [Connect to MySql database through xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528473/connect-to-mysql-database-through-xamarin) it explains why it is a bad idea to connect an app directly to a DB. Instead you're better of connecting through a webservice.